# Mostly PJAX site with some AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pjax

I have a site using PJAX all over the place and I have a few pages that are using AngularJS. For the AngularJS pages I would like to continue to use PJAX to get all the benefits associated with not reloading the entire HTML page, assets etc. <strike>Unfortunately, PJAX just loads some HTML into the page and doesn't fire any javascript. This is okay, because I can fire the javascript manually on pjax success, but I can't quite figure out what makes AngularJS initialize.</strike>

For a simple scenario, lets say I AJAX the following HTML into a page. Also assume, the page already had Angular.js included. What could I call to have the following behave like an Angular App?

```
<div>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
  <hr>
  <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: `$compile` service may be used.

Comment: Manual Initialize is proving quite usefull, http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap ... its working with the exception that something is converting my mustaches }} in hrefs to %20%7D%7D ... I'm now trying to figure what is doing that or what can be done about it.  AngularJS is working where the }} aren't being encoded.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`angular.bootstrap(...)` didn't quit work for me, it was throwing an

> Already existing App Error.

So I went for the `(re)$compile` solution, but the docs are sparse when it comes to using angular from outside the framework (e.g how do you call $compile). After a lot of trial & error this works for me although there might be some overhead :

```
  // outside of angular...
  var ngRefresh = function() {
    var scope = angular.element("body").scope();
    var compile = angular.element("body").injector().get('$compile');

    compile($("body").contents())(scope);
    scope.$apply();
  }

  // PJAX
  $('#page').on('pjax:success', function(e){
    ngRefresh();
  });
```

Comment: Doesn't this leave remaining elements in the scope? When trying this locally my scope is getting bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Manual Initialize worked just fine

```
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
     angular.bootstrap(document);
   });
```

I ended up having some issues with the gem rack-pjax because it was escaping the mustaches in my urls, so I just got rid of the middle ware and decided to have the web server detect the pjax in the request and opt-out of a rendering the layout.

Answer (score -1):

Starting from the solution provided by @charlysisto, I added a hook in `pjax:beforeReplace` to clean up the old scope:

```
var cleanupRemovedScopes = function() {
  var $scope = angular.element("body").scope();

    var q = [$scope], scope, first = true;
    while (q.length > 0) {
        scope = q.pop();

        if (!first) {
            scope.$destroy();
        }

        first = false;

        if (scope.$$childHead) {
            q.push(scope.$$childHead);
        }

        if (scope.$$nextSibling) {
            q.push(scope.$$nextSibling);
        }
    }
}

$('#page').on('pjax:beforeReplace', function() {
  var $timeout = angular.element("body").injector().get("$timeout");
  $timeout(function() {
    cleanupRemovedScopes();
  }
}
```

However, the limitation of this cleanup script is, that your PJAX call replaces the whole body.